# the AVD manage in android studio doesn't start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

i have a problem with the AVD manager, i installed Android v5.0.1 and when i lunch the virtual device it doesn't start.
and this is the detail of the problem :

[image]

please help me to solve this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Intel x86 images rather then armeabi-v7a images.

It will work faster compare to arm images.

Update your android studio to use Android Emulator 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you have ran Android Studio in administrator mode (right click the launch icon)